# How to download a Facebook application to the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, facebook, simulator

I am trying to test the single sign on, so I wanted to download the Facebook application to the iPhone simulator.

Where can I download the Facebook application for iPhone and how can I place it on the simulator?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unless you are the developer of that app, and more to the point, you have the source code to build from scratch, you cannot take an app downloaded through the App Store and run it in the simulator. Aside from likely being against Apple's terms and conditions, apps built for devices are built for ARM processors, while apps built for the simulator are actually Mac apps and built for the i386 platform.

I think you'll have to download the Facebook app to your device via iTunes, then build your app for an iOS device and run it on your device via Xcode. You'll need a developer certificate, of course. That's the only way you'll be able to test SSO with the Facebook app, I believe.

Comment: Yep, you have to test on a real device before you can submit to Apple anyway. A refurb iPod touch is cheap.

Comment: Yeah but it would have been nice to have it on the simulator ... makes life easy ... hope FB can provide some basic test app code that we can build from scratch and run it on the simulator for testing!

Answer (score 8):

Now that iOS 6 is released, you can authenticate with Facebook in the simulator directly. Example of how it can be done is on the Facebook developers site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

Comment: Can you provide more detailed answer what should be done in order to achieve it, please?